# I am having this issue in .format() , Can anyone elaborate this to me?

Tags: python-3.x

`print("My result is {result:2.2f}".format(result))` is not working I had to assign result as r to make the code work.

[image]

Comment: Paste code, not screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case, here is the screenshot that the OP linked to:
[image: OP's screenshot image]

What is happening in `In [7]` is that you are giving a keyword `result` inside the braces `{result:2.2f}`, so it expects that keyword to be present in the arguments of `.format()` that you provide later. You have to do it this way:

`print("My result is {result:2.2f}".format(result=result))`

You have done it correctly in `In [8]`, where the `r` in the string matches with the keyword argument `r=result` in the `.format()` and hence it is able to interpret it correctly.

Btw, you could also simply do - `print("My result is {:2.2f}".format(result))`.

This way it will see that you haven't specified anything inside the braces and hence look for positional arguments in the `.format()`, ie: it will look at it in a serial fashion, and hence pick up the first `result` as the value to be formatted at the first braces `{}` in the string.